# using document.getElementById not working on php forms

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So I have here a php timer using javascript, my problem is

this line when even I reached total_seconds to 0 , my form which is named quiz is not auto submitting, anyone can locate whats wrong here?

btw there is no error with my code.

```
if(total_seconds <=0){setTimeout('document.getElementById("quiz").submit()',1);

<div style="font-weight: bold" id="quiz-time-left">

<script type="text/javascript">
var max_time = <?php echo $total_timer1 ?>*60;
var c_seconds  = 0;
var total_seconds =max_time;
max_time = parseInt(total_seconds/60);
c_seconds = parseInt(total_seconds%60);
document.getElementById("quiz-time-left").innerHTML='Time Left: ' + max_time + ' minutes ' + c_seconds + ' seconds';
function init(){
document.getElementById("quiz-time-left").innerHTML='Time Left: ' + max_time + ' minutes ' + c_seconds + ' seconds';
setTimeout("CheckTime()",999);
}
function CheckTime(){
document.getElementById("quiz-time-left").innerHTML='Time Left: ' + max_time + ' minutes ' + c_seconds + ' seconds' ;
if(total_seconds <=0){
setTimeout('document.getElementById("quiz").submit()',1); <-- **my problem**

    } else
    {
total_seconds = total_seconds -1;
max_time = parseInt(total_seconds/60);
c_seconds = parseInt(total_seconds%60);
setTimeout("CheckTime()",999);
}

}
init();
</script>
</div>
```

Here is the whole form dont mind the variables

```
<form action="result.php" method="post" id='quiz'>


<?php
$username=$_SESSION['username'];
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE username='$username'");
$row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1);
$id1 = $row1['id'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM timer WHERE s_id='$id1' AND q_id='$id' ");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

$currenttime = date ("h:i:sa");
$q_start10 = strtotime ($currenttime);
$q_time = $row['q_time'];
$q_endtime = $row['q_endtime'];
$total_timer = $q_endtime - $q_start10; 
$total_timer1 = $total_timer / 60;



?>


    <font size="6">
<div style="font-weight: bold" id="quiz-time-left"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var max_time = <?php echo $total_timer1 ?>*60;
var c_seconds  = 0;
var total_seconds =max_time;
max_time = parseInt(total_seconds/60);
c_seconds = parseInt(total_seconds%60);
document.getElementById("quiz-time-left").innerHTML='Time Left: ' + max_time + ' minutes ' + c_seconds + ' seconds';
function init(){
document.getElementById("quiz-time-left").innerHTML='Time Left: ' + max_time + ' minutes ' + c_seconds + ' seconds';
setTimeout("CheckTime()",999);
}
function CheckTime(){
document.getElementById("quiz-time-left").innerHTML='Time Left: ' + max_time + ' minutes ' + c_seconds + ' seconds' ;
if(total_seconds <=0){
    setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("quiz").submit()},1000)

    } else
    {
total_seconds = total_seconds -1;
max_time = parseInt(total_seconds/60);
c_seconds = parseInt(total_seconds%60);
setTimeout("CheckTime()",999);
}

}
init();
</script>

</font>
<br>

<br>
<?php
$score = 0;
$tbl_name2="a_quiz"; // Switch to table "forum_answer"
$sql2="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name2 WHERE q_id='$id'";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
$q_question = $rows['q_question'];
?>

<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr style='overflow:hidden; word-wrap:break-word;'>
<p hidden>
    <input type="text" name="q_id" value="<?php echo $rows['q_id'];?>">
    </p>
<td bgcolor="lightgreen"><strong>Question:</strong></td>
<td bgcolor="lightgreen">:</td>
<td bgcolor="lightgreen" style="max-width: 1000px;"><?php echo $rows['q_question']; ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td bgcolor="lightgreen"><strong>A</strong></td>
<td bgcolor="lightgreen">:</td>
<td bgcolor="lightgreen"><input type="radio" name="<?php echo $rows['a_id']; ?>" value="a"><?php echo $rows['a'] ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="18%" bgcolor="lightgreen"><strong>B</strong></td>
<td width="5%" bgcolor="lightgreen">:</td>
<td width="77%" bgcolor="lightgreen"><input type="radio" name="<?php echo $rows['a_id']; ?>" value="b"><?php echo $rows['b'] ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="18%" bgcolor="lightgreen"><strong>C</strong></td>
<td width="5%" bgcolor="lightgreen">:</td>
<td width="77%" bgcolor="lightgreen"><input type="radio" name="<?php echo $rows['a_id']; ?>" value="c"><?php echo $rows['c'] ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="lightgreen"><strong>D</strong></td>
<td bgcolor="lightgreen">:</td>
<td bgcolor="lightgreen"><input type="radio" name="<?php echo $rows['a_id']; ?>" value="d"><?php echo $rows['d'] ?></td>
</tr>


</table></td>
</tr>
<hr>
</table><br>
 <?php
}
?>
<?php

$connection=mysql_connect('localhost', 'root','');
mysql_select_db('thesis');

$username= $_SESSION['username'];


$query6 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE username='$username'");
$row6 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query6);
$s_id = $row6['id'];
$fname = $row6['f_name'];
$mname = $row6['m_name'];
$lname = $row6['l_name'];
$email = $row6['email'];
$position = $row6['position'];
    ?>
<p hidden>
<input type="text" name="s_id" value="<?php echo $s_id ?>">
</p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Answer" class="btn">
</form>
```

Comment: `setTimeout({document.getElementById("quiz").submit()},1)` remove `'` single quotes from the above line..

Comment: setTimeout(document.getElementById("quiz").submit(),1); like this one ?

Comment: Sorry, with an `anonymous function` like this - `setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("quiz").submit()},1)`

Comment: setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("quiz").submit()},1) tried this still not working

Comment: It's really hard to see what is going on here. Try showing the client side code (i.e. *after* PHP has been executed) and making use of white space to format it so it is readable.

Comment: It would also help if you provided enough code to actually reproduce the problem (a minimal about of HTML so that the code which tries to access things in the DOM has something to access for example).

Comment: If there is no error, how have you determined that the problem is on the line `setTimeout('document.getElementById("quiz").submit()',1); <-- **my problem**`?

Comment: cause it suppost to function if my timer reaches <= 0, but its not

Comment: How are you determining if the timer has reached <= 0? How are you determining if the `if` statement is being called at all? Please also address my two earlier comments.

Comment: cause the timer is running and when it reache 0 min 0 sec , updated ive shown all the code of form quiz

Comment: Don't show "all of the code", nobody wants to wade through all of that, especially when it lacks indentation or any idea what is actually in the database. Show a readable test case. http://sscce.org/ is a useful read.

Comment: Since you say that there are no errors, the problem are you are experiencing has nothing to do with the line you've selected. If the problem *was* there, you would get an error (and when you fix whatever problem you do have, you will get one). http://jsbin.com/yigoto/1/edit?html,js,console

Comment: ok sorry for showing all the code with wrong format,. i guess i dont know where my problem is comin from

Comment: That's part of the point in creating a test case. It helps you narrow down the problem while providing a reasonable sized and formatted chuck of code for other people to help you with.

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout expects function as a first parameter and followed with the time delay. [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

```js
function delayAlert(){
   alert("setTimeout has been called");
}
setTimeout(delayAlert, 1000);
```

Comment: define a function with your code and pass it to setTimeout function.
function submitMyform(){
   document.getElementById("quiz").submit();
}
setTimeout(submitMyform,1);

Comment: still not working, or should i also need to put the that script under the line of submit? or doesnt care where line you put the javascript

Comment: That's best practise, but it also accepts a string to be evaluated so that isn't the problem.